# Corolla EVAP Canister Location

Tags: toyota, fuel-system, corolla, evap

i’ve recently have problems with filling up my fuel tank because the pump keep shutting off early. Most youtube videos point to the evap charcoal canister to see if it’s clogged up. But I can’t see where my evap canister is. It’s a 2010 Corolla hatchback (Corolla Auris). Any help much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

From [this](https://paultan.org/2016/06/29/toyota-charcoal-canister-recall/) page about a recall for these cars, it looks like it is mounted in the top of the fuel tank.  There may be a panel under the carpet that you need to remove to get access -

[image]